# KQL - Get Sum of values of Multiple Columns

Tags: azure, kql, azure-data-explorer, kusto-explorer

I get the following data from a query:

```
Service 201 202 401  // 402 etc
A       100 50  20   
C       25  0   0
```

The columns are dynamic. It sometimes there can be just 201, sometimes 200, 201, 202, 204, etc

I want to get the following result:

```
Service 201 202 503  2xxCount  5xxCount
A       100 50  20   150       20        
C       25  0   0    25        0
```

As I said, the columns are dynamic. i want to calculate sum of all columns whose name starts with 2, as 2xxCount and 5 as 5xxCount.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in 2 steps - first generate the query dynamically, and then execute it:

1. Generate query:

```
let T = datatable (Service:string, ['201']:long, ['202']:long, ['401']:long)
[
    "A", 100, 50, 20, 
    "C", 25, 0, 0
];
T | getschema 
| where ColumnName != "Service"
| extend Column = bin(tolong(ColumnName), 100)
| summarize make_list(strcat("['", ColumnName, "']")) by Column
| project strcat("['", Column/100, "xxCount'] = ", strcat_array(list_, " + "))
| summarize ExtendedColumns = strcat_array(make_list(Column1), ", ")
```

| ExtendedColumns |
| --- |
| ['2xxCount'] = ['201'] + ['202'], ['4xxCount'] = ['401'] |

2. Run it:

```
let T = datatable (Service:string, ['201']:long, ['202']:long, ['401']:long)
[
    "A", 100, 50, 20, 
    "C", 25, 0, 0
];
T
| extend ['2xxCount'] = ['201'] + ['202'], ['4xxCount'] = ['401']
```

| Service | 201 | 202 | 401 | 2xxCount | 4xxCount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 100 | 50 | 20 | 150 | 20 |
| C | 25 | 0 | 0 | 25 | 0 |

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve this by a combined use of `narrow` and `pivot`:

```
let T = datatable (Service:string, ['201']:long, ['202']:long, ['401']:long)
[
    "A", 100, 50, 20, 
    "C", 25, 0, 0
];
let categorizedData=T
| evaluate narrow()
| parse Column with "['" Code "']"
| extend Column = coalesce(Code, Column)   // strip the [' '] from the column names
| extend CodeCategory = strcat(toint(Code)/100, 'xx');
let sumByCategory=categorizedData
| where isnotempty(Code)
| summarize Value=tostring(sum(toint(Value))) by Column=CodeCategory, Row;
categorizedData
| union sumByCategory
| project-away Code, CodeCategory
| evaluate pivot(Column, take_any(Value))
| project-away Row
```

Result:

| 201 | 202 | 2xx | 401 | 4xx | Service |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 25 | 0 | 25 | 0 | 0 | C |
| 100 | 50 | 150 | 20 | 20 | A |

Only slightly annoying bit is that you have no control over the column order returned by `pivot` but if the max number of columns is fixed you can hard-code a re-order if it's important to you.